# Ordering Ajax Calls

Tags: ajax, list, jquery

I want the ajax calls that are being made to be in a particular order, Let me explain further using some code.

```
var feed_urls = [
                       'URL_1',
                       'URL_2',
                       'URL_3',
                       ...
                       ...

                       'URL_N',
                       ];
```

I am making ajax calls using jquery's `getJSON` method like so

```
$.each(feed_urls,function(index,value){
                        $.getJSON(value, function(data) {
                            $.each(data.feed.entry,function(i,val){
                                   LIST.push(val.content.src);
                            });
                        });
                });
```

The problem I am facing is that since ajax calls are asynchronous the content of `LIST` is not always in the same order. Is there anyway to solve this ?

The preferable order of ajax calls would be `URL_1` followed by `URL_2` followed by `URL_3` and so on till `URL_N`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ajaxSetup() with async :false, in it re:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
    {
    data: "{}",
    async false,
..whatever else you need
```

Comment: This has the side-effect of freezing *all* javascript on the page while the requests are being performed.

Comment: I don't think Freezing the page would be a problem because All the content is really loaded via the ajax calls , and the ordering is quite important. Let me check it out .

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to only start the request for URL2 after URL1 has completed :

```
function get(n,callback) {
  if (n == feed_urls.length) callback();
  $.getJSON(feed_urls[n], function(data) {
    $.each(data.feed.entry,function(i,val){
      LIST.push(val.content.src);
    });
    get(n+1,callback);
  });
}

get(0,function(){
  // This is called when all lists have been loaded.
  alert(LIST);
});
```

Comment: This has the side effext of not doing anything with the results until all requests have finished :)  it is a trade off compared to the option I posted - the OP will need to decide :) - nice option BTW though.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Your code doesn't do anything with the results as well? This solution has the benefit of *being able* to do other work while the requests are running - it's asynchronous.